# More elegant way to remove from array if exists, push if it doesn't

Tags: javascript

I have an array `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`, and an item `'b'`. Right now I'm doing this:

```
if(!arr.includes(item)){
  arr.push(item);
}else{
  const index = arr.findIndex(it => it === item);
  arr.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Is there a better or more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Is there more context you can provide for this problem?  Like, is order important?  What specifically are you doing that has this requirement?  I ask, because `Set` might be better than array.

Answer (score 3):

You're currently sometimes iterating through the array *twice*: once to check with `.includes`, and again with `findIndex`.

Another issue is that `findIndex` is unnecessarily verbose - an easier method would be to just use `indexOf`.

Use `.indexOf` once:

```
const index = arr.indexOf(item);
if (index === -1) {
  arr.push(item);
} else {
  arr.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Both `.findIndex()` and `.includes()` are of *O(n)* [algorithmic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). For more elegant solution (whatever that means for you) consider using `Set`s:

```js
const set = new Set(items); // for example: new Set([ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ])

if (set.has(item))
  set.delete(item);

else
  set.add(item);
```

Also, as Nina Scholz has correctly pointed out in the comment, the return value of [`Set.prototype.delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/delete) allows for even more concise code:

```js
const set = new Set(items);

set.delete(item) || set.add(item);
```

If `item` *is not* present in the `set`, then `set.delete(item)` will return `false`, which will trigger `set.add(item)`.

If `item` *is* present in the `set`, then `set.delete(item)` will return `true` and the code will stop right there.

Comment: you could take an even shorter approach without `has` by `set.delete(item) || set.add(item)`, because `delete` returns a boolean value, if successfull the `true`, otherwise `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a single iteration.

```
const index = arr.findIndex(it => it === item);

if (index === -1) arr.push(item);
else arr.splice(index, 1);
```